Tensorflow can't detect GPU in aarch64 linux system
I have been trying to use the NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3070 in my linux system(Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) for Tensorflow model training. Unfortunately, Tensorflow couldn’t detect the GPU. I have tried updating all the drivers and libraries.
I have tried installing all the required drivers and libraries for Tensorflow and NVIDIA GPU
List of drivers installed for GPU:
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic)
> nvidia-driver-515, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-515)
> nvidia-driver-520, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-520)
> nvidia-driver-555-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-555-open)
> nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic)
> nvidia-driver-545, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545)
> nvidia-driver-525, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-525)
> nvidia-driver-555, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-555)
> nvidia-driver-550, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic)
> nvidia-driver-545-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545-open)
> nvidia-driver-535-server-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-open-generic)
> nvidia-driver-550-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-open-generic)
> nvidia-driver-535-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-open-generic)

Installed python libraries:
> tensorflow 2.13.1
> tensorflow-aarch64 2.16.1
> nvidia-cublas-cu12 12.4.2.65
> nvidia-cudnn-cu12 9.1.1.17
> nvidia-dali-cuda120 1.37.1
> nvidia-dali-tf-plugin-cuda120 1.37.1
> nvidia-nvimgcodec-cu12 0.2.0.7
> nvidia-pyindex 1.0.9


After all the installations, I have setup the path also:

CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python3 -c “import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.file)”))
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib

But when I try to get the GPU devices in my PC:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

output is []
I don’t know If I’m missing something here. So I hope to find someone to help me with this issue. What else can I do?

Did you try with a new python virtual environment, then run pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] ?

Oddly enough I tried installing tensorflow[and-cuda] and it didn't work on my computer. So I downgraded to the last version of tensorflow that has been working on my computer and it works again. Maybe they have a packaging error at the moment.

@matt I tried downgrading the tensorflow version but Nvidia drivers seems to be non compatible with that. Could you provide the version numbers of the working libraries?

I'm not using aarch64 so it might not be relevant. I created a new venv and I did pip install --upgrade pip then I did pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]. Everything installed, but it did not detect the GPU. Then I did pip install tensorflow==2.15 and then it "worked"

What kind of aarch64 system is this, exactly? The only officially supported ARM systems I am aware of are either NVIDIA’s Tegra or the AWS gravitron cloud servers. I couldn't imagine a stock PC video card working in either….

@talonmies The system is arm64. I read that tensorflow-aarch64 would support this. But currently I couldn't get the tensorflow training running on GPU

That doesn’t answer my question. arm64 and aarch64 are synonymous. What hardware is this?

@talonmies oops Sorry, Hardware is Ampere Altra HPC system(Arm Neoverse N1)

Ok, that is an SBSA platform system from what I can tell, so I guess it stands a chance that  system itself is supported (although I am super surprised that the consumer PC video card works out of the box). But what is the providence of the Tensorflow version you installed? What does import tensorflow.python.platform.build_info as build; print(build.build_info) print?
